# importing product in magento with category name with slash

Tags: magento, csv, import, magento-1.6

I have a problem in my magento, in my product category it has a name "MANGO/ BANANA".
now in my .csv to import it, it lookd like this.

```
_category
------------
Category/MANGO/ BANANA
```

and i got this error

```
Category does not exists in rows:(..)
```

I think the magento look for the BANANA dir, but my directory name in "MANGO/ BANANA"

does anyone have an idea about my case?
on how can I put "MANGO/ BANANA" in the _category field in my .csv?

thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to escape the '/' yet? ex: Category/MANGO\/ BANANA

Comment: try to wrap the category name in brackets: `"MANGO/ BANANA"`

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the forward slash with a backslash: "MANGO\/ BANANA"

Comment: using doing quoted strings in PHP you will need to escape characters such as '/' with the escape characer which is '\'. therfore:
"MANGO/ BANANA" = "MANGO\/ BANANA".

Answer (score 0):

For categories having slash in their name you must use ASCII character of slash like `&#47;`.

> So here are the steps I took and hopefully this helps anyone that’s run into this problem that doesn’t want to change their category names to remove their /’s all together.
>
> Manage Categories > replace / with `&#47;`
>
> I had over 70 categories to deal with so it was easier to make a import/export profile http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-exportimport-data-in-csv-files.html#gref and edit using Find/Replace in excel/openoffice or you can download an extension to help you.
>
> Open your product spreadsheet, go to the Categories column, using Find/Replace to do the substitution.
>
> Import!
>
> Hopefully this is helpful to you all!

I read this from [this article](https://www.onetakemedia.net/magento/dealing-with-slashes-in-magento-category-names/).